# Pyspark. Create A new column based on multiple columns and multiple rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe below:

| id | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | c | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | c | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | c | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I need to get a new column and get the dataframe below:

| id | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | c | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | c | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | c | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

For the case when `id=1`, newColumn should be 1 because all rows with `feature2` , `feature3` and `feature4` are 0. However, for the case when `id==2` NewColumn should be 0 because `feature2` is 1 when `feature1=a` in this case. Same when `id==3`, NewColumn should be 0 because `feature3` contains 1. Basically, I need to consider all ids individually and check `feature2`, `feature3` and `feature4` columns if they contain 1. How to implement it efficiently in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it needs to check values across rows, you can use `collect_list` of `array` of **feature2**, **feature3** and **feature4** over window partitioned by column **id**, `flatten` the array, check if the array contains any value of `1` using `exists`, then `cast` the negated boolean value to integer. (for Spark version >= 2.4)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn('NewColumn', 
                   expr("""cast(
                             not exists(
                               flatten(
                                 collect_list(array(feature2,feature3,feature4)) over (partition by id)),
                               v -> v = 1)
                             as int)"""))
df.show()

# +---+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
# | id|feature1|feature2|feature3|feature4|NewColumn|
# +---+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
# |  1|       a|       0|       0|       0|        1|
# |  1|       b|       0|       0|       0|        1|
# |  1|       c|       0|       0|       0|        1|
# |  3|       b|       0|       0|       0|        0|
# |  3|       c|       0|       1|       0|        0|
# |  2|       a|       1|       0|       0|        0|
# |  2|       b|       0|       0|       0|        0|
# |  2|       c|       0|       0|       0|        0|
# +---+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```